# Are there examples of Greywater reuse between buildings?

Tags: water, water-management, city-living, greywater

Are there any documented cases or examples about reusing greywater from a particular building in another adjacent building?

For example: Using treated greywater from an office building for toilet flushing in a hotel that's next to it.